# VBA If time is between two times

Tags: vba, date, time, compare

```
i = 1    
For Each cell In Range("D1:D10000")
  If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then Exit For

  Select Case Range("N" & i).Value
    Case 0 To 40
      startTime  = "13:00"
    Case 40 To 60
      secondTime = Range("V" & i).Value
    Case 60 To 100
      finalTime = Range("V" & i).Value
    Case Else

   End Select

  Dim startTime As Date
  Dim secondTime As Date
  Dim finalTime As Date
  Dim timeRef As Date
  timeRef = Range("V" & i).Value

  If timeRef >= startTime And timeRef < secondTime Then 

  ElseIf timeRef >= secondTime And timeRef < finalTime Then

  ElseIf timeRef > finalTime Then

  End If
  i = i + 1
Next
```

Ok, So i'm using the above to try and compare times which are formatted as Dates. They are all fetched from a worksheet which is Custom Formatted as "hh:mm" but I cannot seem to get times to fall within any but the final `elseif`

Argh!

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring the values after you've assigned to them (`startTime`, `secondTime` and `finalTime`). At a minimum, you need to change your code to declare and then assign. (Also, your first if statement is wrong; the first test should simply be `If timeRef < secondTime`.)

```
' Declare variables before assigning values to them
Dim startTime As Date
Dim secondTime As Date
Dim finalTime As Date
Dim timeRef As Date

i = 1    
For Each cell In Range("D1:D10000")
  If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then Exit For

  Select Case Range("N" & i).Value
    Case 0 To 40
      startTime  = "13:00"
    Case 40 To 60
      secondTime = Range("V" & i).Value
    Case 60 To 100
      finalTime = Range("V" & i).Value
    Case Else
      ' You should do something here; what if the cell is empty or invalid?
      ' You end up with no value assigned to anything when leaving the Select
   End Select

  timeRef = Range("V" & i).Value

  If timeRef < secondTime Then 

  ElseIf timeRef >= secondTime And timeRef < finalTime Then

  ElseIf timeRef > finalTime Then

  End If
  i = i + 1
Next
```

Since I don't have any of your data to test against, I have no idea if this will actually work, but it fixes the obvious issues that would *prevent* it from working.

Comment: Sorry ken, I edited out all the irrelevant stuff and mispasted it. I do declare before assigning and the change to the first test didn't make any difference from what I can see